# getting broken image in jsp for byte array image data retrieved using servlet saying "image cannot be opened contains error"

Tags: postgresql, jsp, servlets

My imageDispaly.jsp has

```
<img src="/Elvisxu/imageDisplayProcess.do?id=<%=rs.getString(1)" width="75" height="60"/>
```

to call servlet and its in while loop in jsp.

my servlet class code is as below

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String id = request.getParameter("id");

    String imgLen="";
    try {
    DBManager dm=new DBManager();
    dm.GetConnection();
    String sql="select snap from newapp where applid="+id;
    ResultSet rs=dm.select(sql);
    while (rs.next ())
    {   
        imgLen = rs.getString(1);
        System.out.println(imgLen.length());
        int len = imgLen.length();
        byte [] rb = new byte[len];
        InputStream readImg = rs.getBinaryStream(1);
        System.out.println("readImg "+readImg);
        int index=readImg.read(rb, 0, len);
        System.out.println("index "+index);
        response.reset();
          response.setContentType("image/png");
          response.getOutputStream().write(rb,0,len);
          response.getOutputStream().flush();

    }
    }catch (Exception e) {
         System.out.println(e);
    }
```

I searched on google but I didn't get any reason for this.

I'm using postgresql db getting data from snap column as

> [B@302a7504

any response is appreciable

Answer (score 0):

This problem is because of data in "bytea" column and its solved by using prepared statement while saving data in to snap column(bytea) in newapp table.